# conditional return of different type than the defined generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to use a generic method. but one particular type of object there was some problem, so for that particular type, but I am getting error because of type mismatch. how can I correct this?

```
private static T GetObjectFromFile<T>(string filename)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile AppIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFileStream = AppIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ISFileStream.Length];
            ISFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ISFileStream.Close();
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(MonitorBriefs))
            {
                return JsonParser.ParseMonitorBrief(data);//this is incorrect statement
            }
            else
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to cast to `T` in order to satisfy the compiler's requirements: `return (T)JsonParser.ParseMonitorBrief` which due to the type check and my assumption that the type is actually the same, should really end up just being a formality.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth already tried, it says can not convert from MonitorBrief to T

Comment: You could always try casting to `object` first I suppose, but I'd probably review the design of what you are trying to do if you are having to resort to that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so pretty but try this :

```
private static T GetObjectFromFile<T>(string filename)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile AppIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream ISFileStream = AppIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ISFileStream.Length];
        ISFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ISFileStream.Close();
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MonitorBriefs))
        {
            return (T)(object)JsonParser.ParseMonitorBrief(data);//this is incorrect statement
        }
        else
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible with .NET. You could remove move the if statement outside this method and set the return type to T. Or user a wrapper object where you can set both types and return that.

Casting it to an object shouldnt be an option because you need to cast it back in the code where you call the method

Comment: It shouldn't be an option, but it does work. It moves any cast issues into the runtime.